# Javascript SpiderMonkey SyntaxError: missing : after property id:

Tags: javascript, spidermonkey

I'm using Spider Monkey to make a simple console chess game.
However I keep getting the error `SyntaxError: missing : after property id:` in my enum declaration.

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id:
ChessPiece.js:4:5      var Color = {
ChessPiece.js:4:5 ............^
```

Heres the full code

```
class ChessPiece
{
    var Color = {
        WHITE : 'W',
        BLACK : 'B'
    };

    var Piece = {
        PAWN : 'P',
        ROOK : 'R',
        KNIGHT : 'N',
        BISHOP : 'B',
        QUEEN : 'Q',
        KING : 'K'
    };

    constructor(color, piece)
    {
        this.color = color;
        this.piece = piece;
    }

    toString()
    {
        return this.color + this.piece;
    }
}
```

Edit: Updated enum syntax as var declaration.

Comment: Not a spidermonkey problem, That's not valid in any javascript engine

Comment: @JaromandaX What about it isn't valid? could you clarify.

Comment: the syntax - while enum is a reserved word, I can't find any documentation (MDN, ES2015) that shows how to use it ... correction [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Future_reserved_keywords) documents it as a *future reserved keyword*

Comment: @JaromandaX Ive revised my syntax to the old style. The error still persists.

Comment: Just a guess, but do your keys in the object need to be in quotes? 'WHITE'.

Comment: I think you're using "class" all wrong - the body of a class contains methods and constructors - I see no reference to "vars" in the class [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Comment: Thanks for the help, that was it. Enums can't be defined inside the class body.

Answer (score 0):

I guess enums can't be defined inside the class body. I was able to add them after the class definition.

```
class ChessPiece
{
    constructor(color, piece)
    {
        this.color = color;
        this.piece = piece;
    }

    toString()
    {
        return this.color + this.piece;
    }
}

ChessPiece.Color = {
    WHITE : 'W',
    BLACK : 'B'
};

ChessPiece.Piece = {
    PAWN : 'P',
    ROOK : 'R',
    KNIGHT : 'N',
    BISHOP : 'B',
    QUEEN : 'Q',
    KING : 'K'
};
```

Comment: The problem is NOT with the enum. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is here:

[js classes instance properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Instance_properties)

> Static class-side properties and prototype data properties must be
>   defined outside of the ClassBody declaration

Instance vars must be declared in the constructor with "this".